# Capturing click event on ionic 4 local notification in IOS device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

In my `ionic 4` app I was able to trigger local notification on button click using the `cordova` plugin for local notification ([doc.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications#usage)), but could not figure out a way to capture the event when the user clicks the notification banner. On clicking the notification it just redirects to the app but not entering the `'on click'` function.
It is working fine when tested in android device but no luck with ios.

Thanks in advance for the help.

here is my code:

```
  constructor(
    private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
    public platform: Platform,
  ) {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(notification => {
         console.log('click on notification fired);
     });
  }

  notify() {
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      title: `my test notification`,
      text: `my detailed description`,
      trigger: {
        in: 3000,
        unit: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.SECOND,
      },
    });
   }
```

Here is my ionic info :

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 7.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 4.4.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 10 other plugins)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run my app via the 'ionic Devapp', turns out it wont work in Devapp.

When i tried to run it using `ionic cordova run ios` it worked fine.